# Common module in node.js and browser javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing a node.js app, and I want to use a module I am creating for the node.js server also on the client side.

An example module would be circle.js:

```
var PI = Math.PI;

exports.area = function (r) {
  return PI * r * r;
};

exports.circumference = function (r) {
  return 2 * PI * r;
};
```

and you do a simple

```
var circle = require('./circle')
```

to use it in node.

How could I use that same file in the web directory for my client side javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I share code between Node.js and the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225251/how-can-i-share-code-between-node-js-and-the-browser)

Answer (score 47):

This seems to be how to make a module something you can use on the client side.

https://caolan.org/posts/writing_for_node_and_the_browser.html

mymodule.js:

```
(function(exports){

    // your code goes here

   exports.test = function(){
        return 'hello world'
    };

})(typeof exports === 'undefined'? this['mymodule']={}: exports);
```

And then to use the module on the client:

```
<script src="mymodule.js"></script>
<script>
    alert(mymodule.test());
</script>
```

This code would work in node:

```
var mymodule = require('./mymodule');
```

Answer (score 19):

[image: Browserify]

[Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)

It magically lets you do that.

Comment: Not sure how that actually is used to do what I was looking for. It seems to solve some other problem.

Comment: And browserify keeps getting better and better.

Answer (score 2):

[Webmake](https://github.com/medikoo/modules-webmake) was made to port CommonJS/NodeJS modules to browser. Give it a try