# How can we detect whether our script is launched via command line or via a browser?

Tags: node.js

In PHP, there is the PHP_SAPI variable so in PHP i made :

```
 if('cli' == PHP_SAPI)
 {
   //my code
 }
```

What is the equivalent in Node.JS ?

Comment: i would probably first check the existence of `window` object , also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327164/common-module-in-node-js-and-browser-javascript

Comment: You want to detect if your script is running in Node or not?  Or you want to detect if Node.js was launched with a browser?  If the latter, how are you launching Node.js with a browser?

Comment: I do 'supervisor -q -w fwk-lpcms index.js' My scripts always use Node.js. In fact, I want to know if we come from a Symfony's console task equivalent or if we just want to display a site. Maybe, the simplest way is just to define a variable isConsole = true at the beginning of my console tasks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof Window === 'undefined') {
    //node
}
else {
    //browser
}
```

Or you can make it into a function.

```
function isBrowser() {
    return typeof Window !== 'undefined';
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that Window won't be defined in Node.js

Comment: @Brad Globals are much harder to define in node than the browser.  It obviously can be defined but 99.99% it is not and if it is that code should be deleted.  On the contrary I can say there is no guarantee that `process.title` is not defined in the browser.

Comment: Like I said in my comment above, of course there is no guarantee.  But, I have seen plenty of modules define a `window` object in Node.js to shim in behavior.

Comment: @Brad Just my personal opinion I wouldn't be concerned about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect that you're in Node.js, take a look at `process.title`.

It's better though to detect whatever capability you need, as you want your code to be compatible with as many runtimes as possible.

http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_title

Comment: Of course someone could easily set that in the browser too.

Comment: @OrangeDog Obviously, but someone could set anything, so there is no guaranteed method.  `window` gets defined by several NPM modules.  I've never seen a browser module go and set `process.title`, but it is certainly possible.

Comment: Just an fyi for the popular browserify tool code containing `process.title` packaged with browserify will evaluate to a truthy on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting the name of the global variable might be useful:

```
var global = function(){ return this }()

switch (global.toString().toLowerCase()) {
  case '[object window]':
    return "I'm a browser"
  case '[object global]':
    return "I'm a node.js"
  default:
    return "wat?"
}
```

You still can fake this, but I doubt that anyone will.

Comment: I don't want to distinguish the server side and the client side. I launch my site and it tells to me [object global] with your method so i can't know that it was a command line task more than a website.