# Making a browser and node compatible Javascript library

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to make a javascript library which I would prefer to be compatible with both browsers and node. However, there is some functionality offered in the node API that isn't offered in browsers (such as compression). I know it would be possible to code this functionality in javascript so it would be cross-compatible, but the node native compression will probably perform much better as it is much lower level.

How should I split between browser-compatible code and code that uses node API?

The way I see it, I could do one of the following:

- make 2 separate scripts, one for node and one for browsers
- make my code figure out the environment it is in and act accordingly
- make all my code the same, but lose some performance improvements I would have had in node

What should I do to solve this?

Comment: My preference is your first suggestion. My second preference is your second suggestion. I wouldn't do the third.

Comment: I would probably use RequireJS and its Node adapter. This would allow me to share at least some of the code.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm interested in finding a solution to this problem, too. Is there any way to ensure that a Javascript library works with multiple Javascript implementations (such as Rhino, Node.js, and browser-side Javascript)?

Comment: Use https://github.com/component/component. no asynchronous crap. you could also abstract the browser incompatible parts (ie node zlib for compression, a browser compatible version for the browser) or just add a shim

Comment: Could this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225251/how-can-i-share-code-between-node-js-and-the-browser

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, however, today it is possible easily with [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify). Browserify lets you write nodejs modules with `require()` syntax and have them converted to browser complain code easily!

They even ported `zlib` which you mention to work with it, so that dependency is OK.

I hope this helps future readers, browserify helped me :)