# How to check wether the user is logged in with Firebase on the Client Side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

**EDIT:**

Thank you for your help ! You helped me pinpoint the problem and showed me the solution I was looking for: [Accessing Express.js local variables in client side JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919650/accessing-express-js-local-variables-in-client-side-javascript)

---

**CODE:**

index.ejs

```
$('.UpvoteButton').click(function () {
    if (authdata == null) {
        return res.redirect('/users/login');
    }
    else {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $other = $('.DownvoteButton');
        if ($this.hasClass("on")) {
            $this.removeClass("on");
        } else if (!$this.hasClass('on') && $other.hasClass("on")) {
            $this.addClass('on');
            $other.removeClass("on");
        } else {
            $this.addClass('on');
        } 
    } 
});
```

app.js

```
//Global vars
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.authdata = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    next();
});
```

---

**PROBLEM:**

When I click, nothing happens. It worked before when I didn't have the if-else statement and the redirect statement.

N.B.: This is inside an EJS file. I am using Node.js.

---

**QUESTION:**

What have I done wrong ?

Comment: It's **never** going to work that way, you can't do `res.redirect` on the clientside

Comment: @adeneo I also tried: `window.location.href = "/users/login";`

Comment: That should work, assuming `authdata` is defined, and your condition works

Comment: @Coder1000 forget about your serverside stuff in node, we need a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: What's value of `authdata`?

Comment: My suspicion is that `authdata` is a server-side variable. Let's find out... /popcorn

Comment: @LucasCosta That's another problem I have, log statements don't work :/

Comment: As @Jamiec said, the example provided is difficult to test and debug; please post what the value of `authdata` is. Can you also replace `authdata == null` with `false` to test whether the `else` statement runs?

Comment: @canon, makes sense.

Comment: It is a server side variable. I updated my question.

Comment: you can't access directly server-side variable in the front-end in JQuery

Comment: @LucasCosta Yes, that was the issue. Hmmm. But I need to check wether the user is logged in. Hmmm....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919650/accessing-express-js-local-variables-in-client-side-javascript

Comment: That was it. thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, you're trying to access a server-sided variable on the client side. Check this out: [Accessing EJS variable in Javascript logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289793/accessing-ejs-variable-in-javascript-logic).

Essentially, you'll want to declare the variable on the client side using:

```
<script>
    var authdata = <%= authdata %>            
</script>
```

Then, you can add your code. Remember to change the redirect to something that is recognized by the client ie. `window.location.href = "/users/login";`