# Message is not defined

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am following a tutorial to create a sign up page using Nodejs and Mysql: https://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/node-js-user-authentication-using-mysql-express-js/

But somehow encountered into the issue below which I could not find any solution. Hope you guys can help. Thanks in advance!

Error log

```
ReferenceError: C:\Users\User\Desktop\nodejstest\nodejsmysql\webapp\views\index.ejs:18
    16|  
    17|                     <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >
 >> 18|                                                                         <% if (message.length > 0) { %>
    19|                                                                                     <div class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"><%= message %></div>
    20|                                                                         <% } %>
    21|                            

message is not defined
```

Index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
exports.index = function(req,res){
    var message = '';
    res.render('index',{message: message});
}



router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Index.ejs

```
         <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >
                                                                <% if (message.length > 0) { %>
                                                                            <div class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"><%= message %></div>
                                                                <% } %>
```

Comment: The variables in EJS or other view engines need to be declared on the .ejs file like: var message = <%= message %>; Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289793/accessing-ejs-variable-in-javascript-logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exports.index = function(req,res){
    var message = '';
    res.render('index',{message: message});
}

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

This isn't right.

You've not followed the tutorial to the letter.
To get it working, remove the `exports.index` bit, and just do:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var message = '';
  res.render('index', {message: message});
});
```

In your example, from the tutorial, you've missed

> Step 5: Created a new file routes/index.js

and are just returning `{ title: 'Express' }` to your view - no `message`

Comment: Index.js is already there when I install express into the project. What I did was replacing the code with what was shown "/*
* GET home page.
*/
 
exports.index = function(req, res){
    var message = '';
  res.render('index',{message: message});"

Anyway, your solution works. Thanks.