# How to pass EJS variable to external JS file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a variable I am sending to the client side via `res.render()`.

My question is if I have an external JS file that I use for that HTML page, how can I grab the EJS variables that I had send via `res.render()`.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing EJS variable in Javascript logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289793/accessing-ejs-variable-in-javascript-logic)

Comment: How about using EJS to pass through variables, you import external JS into the `res.render()` file?