# how to access ejs object parameters in script file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, ejs

I'm using express server with ejs templates for client and im passing an **object** not a single variable from server to client side.. like

```
router.get('/users/info',(req,res)=>{
  let data = {
    name:"myName",
    email:"me@email.com",
    address:"x,y,z",
    coordinates:{ lat:34.545, lng:78.345 }
 }
res.render('myEJSfile',{data});
})
```

In myEJSfile.ejs file

```
<div id="_data" data-params="<%=data.name%>"></div>
<script>
  let data = document.getElementById('_data').dataset.params;
  console.log(data);
</script>
```

**OUTPUT** :  *myName*

which is expected output

*But when I try to log whole object..* **Again in myEJSfile.ejs :**

```
<div id="_data" data-params="<%=data%>"></div>
<script>
  let data = document.getElementById('_data').dataset.params;
  console.log(data);
</script>
```

**OUTPUT** :  *[object Object]*

*here i want to display a complete valid object passed as a parameter from server side as i need to access on each and every attribute of this object seperately*

Guys im stuck i have no other way in this particular situation get me out of this

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289793/accessing-ejs-variable-in-javascript-logic

Comment: @dikuw it worked but there is one more thing.. if i want to use name only in script file how may i do that.. if i use `data.name` in **script tag** it displays undefined in console