# Sharing Code between Node.js and the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a project that uses Node.js. I'm familiar with JavaScript, but not great. As part of that, I've run into a challenge that I'm not sure how to overcome.

I need to share some code on the server (Node.js) and my client-side (browser) app. I want to be able to access this code by typing the following:

```
myCompany.myProject.myFunction(someValue);
```

or just

```
myProject.myFunction(someValue);
```

In an attempt to do this, I have the following:

```
'use strict';

var myCompany = myCompany || {};
var myProject = myCompany.myProject || {};

myProject.myFunction= function(someValue) {
  console.log(someValue);
};
```

Inside of myFunction, I want to one thing if I'm running on the server (Node.js) and something different if I'm running in the browser. However, I'm not sure how to do that. I reviewed [this post](http://caolanmcmahon.com/posts/writing_for_node_and_the_browser/) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225251/how-can-i-share-code-between-node-js-and-the-browser), yet I still don't understand it.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
function someFunctionName() {

    // Common functional

    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
        // Do something only in Node.JS
    } else {
        // Do something else in the browser
    }

    // Common functional
}
```